# Overriding rails #destroy argument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

#### My Goal:

Override the #destroy method in rails so that gems like Devise will perform a soft-delete.

#### My Attempt:

```
def destroy(mode = :soft)  
  if mode == :hard  
    super  
  else  
    ... soft-delete actions ...  
  end  
end
```

When this is called on the object it get...
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

I would like for this to default to soft-deleting, but have the option to fully destroy the object. My approach may not be the best way to do this, but any advice would help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be

```
super()
```

Here's the full implementation

```
def destroy(mode = :soft)  
  if mode == :hard  
    super()
  else  
    ... soft-delete actions ...  
  end  
end
```

The reason is because when you call `super` without passing any argument, Ruby will call the parent method passing the same arguments that are passed to the original method.

But because the original `destroy` method in Rails takes no argument, the result is the error

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

because your call is translated into

```
if mode == :hard  
  super(mode)
```

Using `super()` (with empty `()`) forces Ruby to pass no arguments to the parent method.

As a side note, I normally prefer to "rename" the old object, instead of overriding it.

```
alias _destroy destroy

def destroy(mode = :soft)  
  if mode == :hard  
    _destroy
  else  
    ... soft-delete actions ...  
  end  
end
```

In this way you will still retain a reference to the original _destroy.

Even better, I prefer to expose a custom API instead of overriding Rails default methods. It helps me to expose a custom API loosely coupled to ActiveRecord internals.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I'll mark it answered in 10 min when it allows me to.

Comment: I updated the answer with a few additional suggestions.

Comment: I like the idea of the alias. I have never used that before, but will be looking at that. It does make it more explicit.