# What's the best way to conditionally override ActiveRecord's deletion mechanism?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, overriding

I am trying to hijack Rails' deletion mechanism to make it behave differently for a certain set of models.

Both `ActiveRecord::Base#delete` and `#destroy` lead back to `ActiveRecord::Relation#delete_all`, so it would make sense to override this method.

**I have tried...**

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << all
    def delete_all
      "My destruction mechanism"
    end
  end
end
```

**... but `::all` is a method that returns a different object every time...**

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.all
    super.tap do |obj|
      class << obj
        def delete_all
          "My destruction mechanism"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**... but `::all` isn't the *only* scope that needs it overridden anyway...**

```
class ActiveRecord::Relation
  def delete_all(*args)
    "My destruction mechanism"
  end
end
```

**... but it can *only* apply to MyModel and its subclasses...**

```
class ActiveRecord::Relation
  def delete_all(*args)
    if @klass.new.is_a?(MyModel)
      "My destruction mechanism"
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

**... but this causes stack overflows on other models.**

Help?

Comment: Have you looked through this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20553635/1208166)? Might be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding `delete` and `destroy` on your model should accomplish most of what you want. Check out how the [Paranoia](https://github.com/radar/paranoia) gem accomplishes its overriding. The library's only 200 lines or so, and also handles associated models (eg when you have `dependent: :destroy`).

Comment: I ended up just overriding `#delete`, as it happens. If I needed I could probably alias `#destroy` to the same thing.